# How to test sponsored posts via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm working on creating Facebook post automatically from a CMS. I've set up GRAPH API calls (POST [https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage_id%7D/feed)) to create posts when publishing new articles which is working great.

However I also wanted to create sponsored posts. To do this, I'm supplying the page ID of our sponsor as the "sponsor_id" parameter of the call as per dev docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/branded-content). Before providing this feature to our users, I wanted to make sure this process is working as intended, I've create a Test APP on facebook which is a copy of our current APP, I've created a test user as well. Making a post works but when I provide a page's ID as a sponsor I receive the below error. I even tried using a page ID of a business we've had as a sponsor previously thinking that since the app is a copy of our current app it might work but I still get:

`{"error":{"message":"(#100) sponsor_id requires publishing profile\/page to be verified or branding partner.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"XXX"}}`

I've tried creating a second page, thinking if I was admin of both pages, this would work but nope...

How can I go about testing this feature? Who can I add a sponsor to test? I can't seem to find anything in the facebook docs about testing this.

Comment: I am facing the same exact problem and i can't test it :/
did you ever figure it out?